# Adding together data by time segment in r

Tags: r

I have a very large data set that I am trying to make smaller. For the purpose of this question I will simplify it by focusing only on a few of the variables. I have samples taken from many subjects once every 5 minutes for three hours and I would like to add together every 2 time segments. Instead of using 5 minute intervals I would like to switch to 10 minute intervals.

Data:

```
ID  Time  Measurement
A1  5     2
A1  10    3
A1  15    2
A1  20    4
A2  5     0
A2  10    3
A2  15    3
A2  20    0
```

I would like to turn this into:

```
ID  Time  Measurement
A1  10    5
A1  20    6
A2  10    3
A2  20    3
```

How would I make this happen in R?

Comment: Is your time variable actually in multiples of 5 like this?

Comment: Yes, it goes from 5 to 180. I have data of the number of times an animal performed a certain behavior every 5 minutes. Measurement just refers to one of the 10 variables I am subsetting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `findInterval` and `aggregate` in some way... something like the following, perhaps:

```
mydf$newTime <- findInterval(mydf$Time, seq(1, 180, 10)) * 10

## Or, as suggested by G. Grothendieck
mydf$newTime <- 10 * ((mydf$Time - 5) %/% 10) + 10
```

"mydf" now looks like this:

```
mydf
#   ID Time Measurement newTime
# 1 A1    5           2      10
# 2 A1   10           3      10
# 3 A1   15           2      20
# 4 A1   20           4      20
# 5 A2    5           0      10
# 6 A2   10           3      10
# 7 A2   15           3      20
# 8 A2   20           0      20
```

From here, we can easily use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Measurement ~ ID + newTime, mydf, sum)
#   ID newTime Measurement
# 1 A1      10           5
# 2 A2      10           3
# 3 A1      20           6
# 4 A2      20           3
```

I haven't tested this on anything but your sample data though....

Comment: or perhaps `mydf$newTime <- 10 * ((mydf$Time - 5) %/% 10) + 10`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, that is probably a safer option.

Comment: I think this worked but I have another question now. How can I add this consolidated information to my data set. I understand there is a difference in rows between the compressed data and the original but I want to be able to plot and run some analyses on this data now.

Comment: @user3478656, I don't quite understand your follow-up question (and that's not typically how things work here at SO). However, it sounds like you might want to look at `merge`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I just made a new data frame with the aggregated data, I was trying to see if there was an option to add the aggregated data to  my current data frame.

Comment: @user3478656, then, yes, look at `merge`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Great. I did realize one problem I am having. I have one other variable (Treatment) for each ID. How would I go about aggregating the data by newTime and Treatment. possibly this: aggregate(NOperantBehav ~ ID + newTime + Treatment, c1.sub, sum)

Comment: @user3478656, you mean you want to aggregate the values in "Treatment" or "Treatment" is like another ID variable?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Each ID has two treatment groups-one receives the treatment the other is a yoked control